# Запрос на уникальность фамилии

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица users в которой имя и фамилия в разных колонках, нужно вывести юзеров в одной колонке  но только тех, у кого не повторяются фамилии.
Нашел метод DISTINCT 
Но там проблема, я должен в селекте конкатинировать колонку, а значит дистинкт будет искать повторы по целой строке, а не только по фамилии, таким образом, повторяющиеся фамилии выводятся

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONCAT(users.name, ' ', users.surename)
FROM users
GROUP BY users.surename;
```

Если после дистинкта добавить просто `users.surename` то все выведет нормально, но не знаю как добавить вначало users.name после вывода.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(users.name, ' ', users.surename)
FROM users
GROUP BY users.surename HAVING COUNT(users.surename) = 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(users.name) name, CONCAT(MAX(users.name), ' ', users.surename) fullname
FROM users
GROUP BY users.surename 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT users.name) = 1;
```

Дополнительно устранена проблема. когда один и тот же юзер занесён в таблицу дважды. Зато не обнаруживаются полные тёзки - впрочем, озвученные данные не позволяют их различить.

Comment: А можно как то не выводить первый столбик name?

Comment: @DonnieDarko Уберите, какие проблемы-то?